# socket.io-client: Can't call the "connect" function

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have the following code:

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');

function connect_to_room(callback){
    console.log(typeof io.connect);
    var socket = io.connect('http://website.com/socket/');
    socket.on('connect', function(){
        console.log("connected");
        socket.on('event', function(data){
            console.log("event happened");
            console.log(data);
        });
        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
            console.log("disconnected");
        });
    });
}

exports.connect = connect_to_room();
```

When I call `connect_to_room()`, it logs "function" in the console, and then throws me this error:

```
TypeError: Property 'connect' of object #<Object> is not a function
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\randomuser\Downloads\somecode\somecode\dev\init.js:151:35)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\randomuser\Downloads\somecode\somecode\dev\node_modules\request\request.js:121:22)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\randomuser\Downloads\somecode\somecode\dev\node_modules\request\request.js:978:14)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\randomuser\Downloads\somecode\somecode\dev\node_modules\request\request.js:92
9:12)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

`node --version` returns `v0.10.26`

package.json has this for dependencies (which are all installed):

```
"dependencies" : {
    "jsonfile"          : "1.1.1",
    "log4js"            : "0.6.12",
    "mkdirp"            : "0.3.5",
    "npm"               : "1.4.4",
    "request"           : "2.34.0",
    "jsdom"             : "0.10.2",
    "socket.io-client"  : "0.9.16"
},
```

Comment: Unless your socket server (the thing you're trying to connect to) is on port 80, try doing `io.connect('http://website.com/socket/',{port:3000});`. Replace 3000 with whatever port your socket server is running on.

Comment: @Houseman I'm trying to connect as a client, and not run a server, and the socket server is running on port 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo

```
var sock
```

should be

```
var socket
```

Another problem:

```
exports.connect = connect_to_room();
```

Should be

```
exports.connect = connect_to_room;
```

Comment: Sorry about that. The issue is that even if I had the variables right, it would still throw the error.

Comment: Just did `require('log4js')` as a test and then did `require('socket.io')` in the node console in the same directory. That doesn't work, but `require('socket.io-client')` does.

Comment: Also, I'm not trying to run a server, but rather connect as a client. Every resource I looked at told me to use `socket.io-client` instead of `socket.io`

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that! I'll check and see if this fixes it.

Comment: It fixed it! Thanks! I'll be more careful next time. :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://website.com/socket/');

function connect_to_room(callback){
    console.log(typeof io.connect);
    socket.on('connect', function(){
        console.log("connected");
        socket.on('event', function(data){
            console.log("event happened");
            console.log(data);
        });
        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
            console.log("disconnected");
        });
    });
}

exports.connect = connect_to_room(function(back){ });
```

Comment: The `require('socket.io-client')(url)` is meant to be used for socket.io v1.x, while `require('socket.io-client').connect(url)` is meant for v0.9.x

Comment: @Ivan gah! Stupid documentation for versions that don't exist yet!

Comment: Yeah, LearnBoost is being a bit ahead of their documentation as of late; this should mean that v1.x will soon be here